# Removing from a hashmap a specific value and the key

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I want to remove a specific value from the `hashmap` and the key from that value. Look, for example if I have

```
hashMap.put(cold, frozen)
hashMap.put(cold,hard)
```

, in my graphic interface i will have `cold=[frozen,hard]`.If I want to erase `hard` I want `cold = [frozen]` to stay

My hashMap is `private HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hashMap ;`
Here is what I tried but it's not good enough because if I have at 2 different key the value i want to remove, it only removes the value for the first and if I have for ex `cold=[frozen,hard]` and I erase hard it doesn't keep `cold=[frozen];`

```
for(String key : hashMap.keySet()){
    int siz = hashMap.get(key).size();
    for(int i = 0; i< siz;i++){

        if(hashMap.get(key).get(i).equals(cuvant)){
            s.remove(hashMap.get(key).get(i));
            siz--;
            hashMap.remove(key);

        }
    }
}
```

I forgot to mention that s is the `arrayList` with the values.

Comment: Just a little hint: You could declare your Map as `Map<String, List<String>> hashMap` - if possible, you should always program against interfaces, not implementations.

Comment: what is `s` in `s.remove(hashMap.get(key).get(i));`?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention. Is the array that contains the values.

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code.  First, calling `hashMap.put( "cold", "frozen")` won't even work.  You've created a `Map` where the values are instances of `List`.  Trying to add a string will fail.  Even if it did work, the second call will just replace the existing value in the map, not add to the list.  Next, as another comment points out, you've got a variable `s` that is not defined.

Comment: I don't have any problem whit putting the items because I put strings and my hash map receive a key as a string and an array of strings as a value. I edited my post with the meaning of string

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing a specific value from the hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987139/removing-a-specific-value-from-the-hashmap)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>>> iter = m.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry = iter.next();
            ArrayList<String> list = entry.getValue();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
                if(list.get(i).equals(cuvant)){
                    list.remove(i);
                }
            }
            if(list.isEmpty())
                iter.remove();
        }
```

Comment: It's not if i saw this answer i would have referred to it  . Anyway i will update the answer to fit arraylist of strings

Comment: @vefthym i think this should do it

Comment: This is it. I was avoiding iterator and hasNext() because I'm not quite familarized with this terms. Thanx a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting an ArrayList with the values in a hashmap?

If so, then check for list size first:

```
if (! hashMap.get(key).isEmpty()){
            hashMap.get(key).remove(ValueToRemoved)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a condition

```
if (hashMap.get(key).isEmpty())
```

before

```
hashMap.remove(key);
```

This will ensure you delete a key only if the list associated with it is completely empty.

---

Also, make sure you do NOT keep iterating (the inner loop) after removing an element from the list if you use a for-each loop, it will get you a `ConcurrentModificationException`. If your list can have the same value multiple times (and should be removed multiple times), use the [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) API rather than for-each loop.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.  In his map he's got a list with N values, and he wants to remove ONE of those values so that a list with N-1 values remains afterwards.

Comment: @BobbyStJacques Yes, it does. You remove a value (as the original code does), and it completely removes the list from the map after it. I answered how to avoid the undesired part, and keep the list with N-1 values.

Comment: Yes, i got that exception. But I don't know about the API iterator. I'll search  for it

Comment: @CrinaHojda This is relevant only if you have say `cold->[frozen,hard,frozen]`, and by deleting "frozen" you want to get `cold->[hard]`. Otherwise, you don't really need the iterator API and you can just use `break` statement at the end of the `if` block.

Comment: @BobbyStJacques how does it NOT answer the question "If I want to erase hard I want cold = [frozen] to stay". That is exactly the anser to this question...

Comment: `isEmpty()` looks better btw, than `size == 0`

Comment: Because, according to his code example, the way that he is adding (and removing) items from his Map is flawed and this suggestion doesn't correct the numerous problems.

Comment: @BobbyStJacques but the question is very specific, and not to debug or optimize the code (and judging by the avatar and the name, I suppose SHE is a woman...)

Comment: @BobbyStJacques You do realize the example for `put()` at the beginning are not real codes and only demonstrates the idea. The later part does explain how it is actually implemented (map where each value is a list), and I can assume the implementation is also adjusted accordingly - because the OP is straggling with an issue at RUN-TIME, and trying to `put(key,element)` in a `Map<Key,List<Element>>` would have caused a *compile time* error.